# Borel and analytic sets - Why did Jech do this?

Tags: set-theory, borel-sets

I've read in Jech's chapter on Borel and analytic sets that there is a universal $\Sigma_{\alpha}^0$ set $U \subseteq \mathcal{N} \times \mathcal{N}$ such that for every $\Sigma_{\alpha}^0$ set $A$ in $\mathcal{N}$, there exists some $a \in \mathcal{N}$ such that:

$$
A = \{x : (x,a) \in U \}
$$

Having constructed $U$, we can construct a new universal set $V$ that is $\Sigma_{\alpha+1}^0$. To construct $V$, Jech uses some continuous mapping of $\mathcal{N}$ onto the product space $\mathcal{N}^{\omega}$ such that:

$$
(x,y) \in V \text{ if and only if for some $n$, } (x,y_{(n)}) \not \in U
$$

where $y_{(n)}$ represents the $n$th coordinate of the image of $y$ in the product space $\mathcal{N}^{\omega}$ under the continuous mapping, which can be some continuous pairing function $\Gamma$, i.e. for instance, we can have $y_{(n)}(k)=y(\Gamma(n,k))$.

I would like to get some help on the intuition behind having to use a continuous mapping to construct $V$. From what I understand, $(x,y) \in V$ if and only if  $x \in \bigcup A_n$ if and only if $(x,y) \not \in U$ (where the $A_n$'s here are $\Pi_{\alpha}^0$ sets) ... Why not just take $(\mathcal{N} \times \mathcal{N}) - U$ to form $V$ ?

Comment: First you say "$(x,y)\in V$ iff for some $n$, $(x,y_{(n)})\notin U$", and then you say "From what I understand, $(x,y)\in V$ iff ... $(x,y)\notin U)$". These are different conditions, so I'm confused about how you arrived at the second conclusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $a\in \mathcal{N}$ and $X\subseteq \mathcal{N}\times \mathcal{N}$, let's define $X_a = \{x\mid (x,a)\in X\}$. In particular, $U_a$ is the $\Sigma^0_\alpha$ set coded by $a$.

Now let's follow your proposal and define $V' = (\mathcal{N}\times\mathcal{N})\setminus U$. Note that $V'$ is the complement of a $\Sigma^0_\alpha$ set, so it is $\Pi^0_\alpha$.

For all $a\in \mathcal{N}$, we have $b\in V'_a$ iff $(b,a)\in V$ iff $(b,a)\notin U$ iff $b\notin U_a$. So $V'_a = \mathcal{N}\setminus U_a$. Since every $\Pi^0_\alpha$ set is the complement of some $\Sigma^0_\alpha$ set of the form $U_a$, we see that $V'$ is a universal $\Pi^0_\alpha$ set.

But the goal here is to find a universal $\Sigma^0_{\alpha+1}$ set, not a universal $\Pi^0_\alpha$ set! So we want to find a $\Sigma^0_{\alpha+1}$ set $V$ such that the sets of the form $V_a$ are arbitrary countable unions of sets of the form $V'_x$. This is the motivation for mapping $\mathcal{N}\to \mathcal{N}^\omega$, so that a single $a\in \mathcal{N}$ can code a countable sequence of sets of the form $V'_{a_{(n)}}$.

Comment: thanks, just to clarify a bit more ... we have that if $(x,y) \in V$ (with $V$ as a $\Sigma_{\alpha+1}^0$ set) implies that $x \not \in U_{a}$ (where $U_a$ is some $\Sigma_{\alpha}^0$ set) ... then this $a$ is the coordinate in $\mathcal{N}^{\omega}$ of the image of $y$ given the continuous function, so that $y$ "encodes" the $a$ coordinates of $\bigcup_a U_a$ such that $(x,y) \in V$ implies that $x \not \in U_a$ for some $a$ ... did I get it right ? really appreciate your awesome help

Comment: @LinkL The definition of $V$ given by Jech is that $(x,y)\in V$ iff $(x,y_{(n)})\notin U$ for some $n$. Unpacking, $(x,y)\in V$ iff $x\notin U_{y_{(n)}}$ for some $n$ iff $x\in \bigcup_{n\in \omega} (\mathcal{N}\setminus A_n)$, where $A_n$ is the $\Sigma^0_\alpha$ set $U_{y_{(n)}}$. Note that the complement of $A_n$ is $\Pi^0_\alpha$, so $V_y$ is a countable union of $\Pi^0_\alpha$ sets, i.e., a $\Sigma^0_{\alpha+1}$ set.

Comment: Going the other way: If $X$ is an arbitrary $\Sigma^0_{\alpha+1}$ set, we can write $X = \bigcup_{n\in \omega} Y_n$, with each $Y_n$ $\Pi^0_\alpha$. Then the complement of $Y_n$ is $\Sigma^0_\alpha$, so it is $U_{y_n}$ for some $y_n\in \mathcal{N}$. Now pick some $y\in \mathcal{N}$ so that $q(y) = (y_n)_{n\in \omega}$, where $q\colon \mathcal{N}\to \mathcal{N}^\omega$ is the continuous surjective map. Then $V_y = \bigcup_{n\in \omega} (\mathcal{N}\setminus U_{y_n}) = X$.

Comment: awesome ! thanks